# Correct use of HttpServletResponse response.reset() and how can I get rid of it

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I have a servlet which returns JSON response. If I do a `response.getWriter` and then do a `response.reset()` and then set the headers and print the output, everything is fine. As soon as I remove the `response.reset()`, I get the exception while running on Jetty server, although I get the output displayed properly in the browser.

```
SEVERE: Error while closing the output stream in order to commit response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:917)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder$1.getOutputStream(ServerRuntime.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.flushBuffer(CommittingOutputStream.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.close(CommittingOutputStream.java:276)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.close(OutboundMessageContext.java:839)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:412)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:750)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:414)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1629)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I checked the [API Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#reset--) but it didnt help at all.

Working code (with response.reset())

```
public Response getData (
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, SQLException, ServletException {
    Writer out = null;
    try {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();

        response.reset();
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.addHeader("content-type", "gzip");

        //Print the output in json format using out.write()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.status(400).entity("{\n\"Error Message\":\"" + StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(e.getMessage().trim()) + "\"\n}").build();
    }
    out.flush();
    return Response.ok().entity("").build();
}
```

I have also tried setting the headers before and then doing a getWriter but that didnt help. Please suggest what exactly response.reset is doing here and is there any way I can get rid of it.

Using Jetty version 9.4.8.v20180619

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WRITER
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:917)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.writeResponseStatusAndHeaders(ResponseWriter.java:176)
```

That is telling you that Jersey attempted to use `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()` after something else had already called `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` prior to that.  That is not allowed in the Servlet spec, and cause the `IllegalStateException` you are seeing.

Why are you generating the response yourself in Jersey with `out = response.getWriter();` ?  Jersey is the one that's responsible for generating the content, not you.

Also, I see that you have `GzipFilter` in your stacktrace ...

```
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51)
```

That's been deprecated since Jetty 9.0, switch to using `GzipHandler` instead.

If you do that, you can remove the `response.addHeader("content-type", "gzip");` call from your code (which you aren't using correctly anyway)

Lastly, in regards to "Using Jetty version 9.4.8.v20180619".  Upgrade your version of Jetty.

Jetty 9.4.8 is [a vulnerable version subject to multiple CVEs](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security-reports.html) and is not safe to use.